# TypeError: No implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer, trying to filter based on arguments

Tags: ruby, regex, case-statement

I'm trying to filter an array of hashes based on the hash parameters passed into the method. I'm new to Ruby with a Javascript background. Right now I'm trying to select based on multiple criteria, in this case rank:4 and quote: /get/.

```
class Where
  @boris = {:name => 'Boris The Blade', :quote => "Heavy is good. Heavy is reliable. If it doesn't work you can always hit them.", :title => 'Snatch', :rank => 4}
  @charles = {:name => 'Charles De Mar', :quote => 'Go that way, really fast. If something gets in your way, turn.', :title => 'Better Off Dead', :rank => 3}
  @wolf = {:name => 'The Wolf', :quote => 'I think fast, I talk fast and I need you guys to act fast if you wanna get out of this', :title => 'Pulp Fiction', :rank => 4}
  @glen = {:name => 'Glengarry Glen Ross', :quote => "Put. That coffee. Down. Coffee is for closers only.", :title => "Blake", :rank => 5}

  @fixtures = [@boris, @charles, @wolf, @glen]

  def self.where(hash = {})
    arr = []
    hash.each_with_index do |key, index|
      hash_value = hash[hash.keys[index]]
      puts arr;
      case hash_value
      when Integer
        puts 'hitting integer'
        if index === 0
          puts 'hitting 1'
          arr.push(@fixtures.select { |obj| obj[hash.keys[index]] === hash[hash.keys[index]] })
        else
          puts 'hitting 2'
          arr.select { |obj| obj[hash.keys[index]] === hash[hash.keys[index]] }
        end
      when String
        puts 'hitting string'
        if index === 0
          puts 'hitting 3'
          arr.push(@fixtures.select { |obj| obj[hash.keys[index]] === hash[hash.keys[index]] })
        else
          puts 'hitting 4'
          arr.select { |obj| obj[hash.keys[index]] === hash[hash.keys[index]] }
        end
      when Regexp
        puts 'hitting Regexp'
        if index === 0
          puts 'hitting 5'
          arr.push(@fixtures.select { |obj| obj[hash.keys[index]].index(hash[hash.keys[index]]) != nil })
        else
          puts 'hitting 6'
          arr.select { |obj|  obj[hash.keys[index]].index(hash[hash.keys[index]]) != nil }
        end
      end
    end
    return self
  end
end

Where.where(:rank => 4, :quote => /get/)
```

What I'm trying to get is [@wolf]

This is what I'm getting from repl.it

hitting integer

hitting 1

{:name=>"Boris The Blade", :quote=>"Heavy is good. Heavy is reliable. If it doesn't work you can always hit them.", :title=>"Snatch", :rank=>4}
{:name=>"The Wolf", :quote=>"I think fast, I talk fast and I need you guys to act fast if you wanna get out of this", :title=>"Pulp Fiction", :rank=>4}

hitting Regexp

hitting 6

Comment: This code is very confusing to read, because you've dug yourself into a big hole... Give me a minute, I'll unravel it for you.

Comment: Please, try to construct a [mcve]. (In your case, I think your example is not minimal.) I'm willing to bet that the problem can be demonstrated in less than 45 lines. Probably less than 4! Hint: the error message should tell you where the error occurs. And you should tell us.

Answer (score 1):

*Short answer*:

The bug is caused by the fact that `arr = []`, then you call `arr.push(<another_array>)`, meaning the variable is an *array of arrays*.

Later, you call `obj[hash.keys[index]]`, but (because of the above), `obj` is actually an **`Array`**, not a `Hash`. This is why you get the `TypeError: no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer` error.

I *could* try to patch your code with a workaround (`Array#flatten` perhaps?), but a much better idea would be to refactor the thing to simplify it massively.

Let's unravel this one step at a time:

1. Why are there all these odd references to `hash.keys[index]`?

Because you're trying to yield 3 variables, but only declaring two - so the first is a mis-named combination of two values. Instead of: `hash.each_with_index do |key, index|`, you need: `hash.each_with_index do |(key, value), index|`. Doing this simplifies the code to:

```
class Where
  @boris = {:name => 'Boris The Blade', :quote => "Heavy is good. Heavy is reliable. If it doesn't work you can always hit them.", :title => 'Snatch', :rank => 4}
  @charles = {:name => 'Charles De Mar', :quote => 'Go that way, really fast. If something gets in your way, turn.', :title => 'Better Off Dead', :rank => 3}
  @wolf = {:name => 'The Wolf', :quote => 'I think fast, I talk fast and I need you guys to act fast if you wanna get out of this', :title => 'Pulp Fiction', :rank => 4}
  @glen = {:name => 'Glengarry Glen Ross', :quote => "Put. That coffee. Down. Coffee is for closers only.", :title => "Blake", :rank => 5}

  @fixtures = [@boris, @charles, @wolf, @glen]

  def self.where(hash = {})
    arr = []
    hash.each_with_index do |(key, value), index|
      puts arr;
      case value
      when Integer
        puts 'hitting integer'
        if index === 0
          puts 'hitting 1'
          arr.push(@fixtures.select { |obj| obj[key] === value })
        else
          puts 'hitting 2'
          arr.select { |obj| obj[key] === value }
        end
      when String
        puts 'hitting string'
        if index === 0
          puts 'hitting 3'
          arr.push(@fixtures.select { |obj| obj[key] === value })
        else
          puts 'hitting 4'
          arr.select { |obj| obj[key] === value }
        end
      when Regexp
        puts 'hitting Regexp'
        if index === 0
          puts 'hitting 5'
          arr.push(@fixtures.select { |obj| obj[key].index(value) != nil })
        else
          puts 'hitting 6'
          arr.select { |obj|  obj[key].index(value) != nil }
        end
      end
    end
    return self
  end
end

puts Where.where(:rank => 4, :quote => /get/)
```

(Note that I haven't yet fixed your error!)

2. Why is there an `arr` variable, and logic surrounding `if index === 0`?

Fixing this requires a slight change in mindset -- your current design could only ever work for checking up to two conditions in the `where` hash, as you're storing the results of the first check in the temporary array. This is unnecessary; you can instead write something like:

```
class Where
  @boris = {:name => 'Boris The Blade', :quote => "Heavy is good. Heavy is reliable. If it doesn't work you can always hit them.", :title => 'Snatch', :rank => 4}
  @charles = {:name => 'Charles De Mar', :quote => 'Go that way, really fast. If something gets in your way, turn.', :title => 'Better Off Dead', :rank => 3}
  @wolf = {:name => 'The Wolf', :quote => 'I think fast, I talk fast and I need you guys to act fast if you wanna get out of this', :title => 'Pulp Fiction', :rank => 4}
  @glen = {:name => 'Glengarry Glen Ross', :quote => "Put. That coffee. Down. Coffee is for closers only.", :title => "Blake", :rank => 5}

  @fixtures = [@boris, @charles, @wolf, @glen]

  def self.where(hash = {})
    @fixtures.select do |fixture|
      hash.all? do |key, value|
        case value
        when Integer
          puts 'hitting integer'
          fixture[key] === value
        when String
          puts 'hitting string'
          fixture[key] === value
        when Regexp
          puts 'hitting Regexp'
          fixture[key] === value
        end
      end
    end
  end
end

puts Where.where(:rank => 4, :quote => /get/)
```

(Woah, that shrunk it a *lot!* - and the `index` variable is now not even needed. This fixes your original bug, but the code won't still quite work...)

3. Comparing `String === Regexp` will always fail.

See [the documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-3D-3D-3D) - you actually need to use `Regexp === String` here, not the other way around. Changing this, finally, gives us **working** code:

```
class Where
  @boris = {:name => 'Boris The Blade', :quote => "Heavy is good. Heavy is reliable. If it doesn't work you can always hit them.", :title => 'Snatch', :rank => 4}
  @charles = {:name => 'Charles De Mar', :quote => 'Go that way, really fast. If something gets in your way, turn.', :title => 'Better Off Dead', :rank => 3}
  @wolf = {:name => 'The Wolf', :quote => 'I think fast, I talk fast and I need you guys to act fast if you wanna get out of this', :title => 'Pulp Fiction', :rank => 4}
  @glen = {:name => 'Glengarry Glen Ross', :quote => "Put. That coffee. Down. Coffee is for closers only.", :title => "Blake", :rank => 5}

  @fixtures = [@boris, @charles, @wolf, @glen]

  def self.where(hash = {})
    @fixtures.select do |fixture|
      hash.all? do |key, value|
        case value
        when Integer
          puts 'hitting integer'
          value === fixture[key]
        when String
          puts 'hitting string'
          value === fixture[key]
        when Regexp
          puts 'hitting Regexp'
          value === fixture[key]
        end
      end
    end
  end
end

puts Where.where(:rank => 4, :quote => /get/)
```

3. It's still very repetitive!...

Perhaps you actually do want that `case` statement with all the `puts` calls for debugging, but otherwise the code can again be simplified quite a lot:

```
class Where
  @boris = {:name => 'Boris The Blade', :quote => "Heavy is good. Heavy is reliable. If it doesn't work you can always hit them.", :title => 'Snatch', :rank => 4}
  @charles = {:name => 'Charles De Mar', :quote => 'Go that way, really fast. If something gets in your way, turn.', :title => 'Better Off Dead', :rank => 3}
  @wolf = {:name => 'The Wolf', :quote => 'I think fast, I talk fast and I need you guys to act fast if you wanna get out of this', :title => 'Pulp Fiction', :rank => 4}
  @glen = {:name => 'Glengarry Glen Ross', :quote => "Put. That coffee. Down. Coffee is for closers only.", :title => "Blake", :rank => 5}

  @fixtures = [@boris, @charles, @wolf, @glen]

  def self.where(hash = {})
    @fixtures.select do |fixture|
      hash.all? do |key, value|
        puts "Checking #{key} => #{value.inspect}"
        value === fixture[key]
      end
    end
  end
end

puts Where.where(:rank => 4, :quote => /get/)
```